# splunk. find count of occurs in each event

Tags: splunk

How to make a query to find the number of occurrences of a string in each event, that is, if a tag occurs more than once in an event, the search should show the number of such tags in each individual event

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

To find the number of occurrences of a specific string, extract the string, count the number of times it appears in each event, then add those numbers.

```
index=foo "bar"
| rex max_match=0 "(?<bars>bar")
| eval bar_count=mvcount(bars)
| stats sum(bar_count) as total_bars
```